# How can I set an INPUT value to '1' for a button event at same DOM level ? What the error of my code

Tags: jquery, input, hidden

My code as follows. Seems I can not precisely locate the input tag with name delete[]. Thanks.

```
<div id="rc1" class="actionitem">
<fieldset>
<legend>Action Item</legend>
<table>
</table>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="aid[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="delete[]">
<button onclick="remove(this);" type="button">Remove</button>
</fieldset>
</div>

<script>
function remove(element){
    if (confirm("Please press OK to confirm")) {
        $(element).parent().find('delete').val('1');
        $(element).parent().parent().slideUp('slow', function() {
            $(element).parent().parent().hide();
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
.find('delete')
```

Why dont you try the selector syntax like

```
.find('input[name="delete[]"]')
```

Comment: Similar to Arash Milani and raj_nt suggestion, but still not work.

Comment: Finally the following code work. Don't know why not work as expected in the beginning. Browser cache ?

    $(element).parent().find('input[name="deleted[]"]').val('1');

Answer (score 0):

You should find the element by its name attribute. change that line to this to get it working

```
$(element).parent().find("input[name='delete[]']").val('1');
```

The way you wrote that code forces the jQuery to look for a `<delete>` element in the `DOM` not a element which has a `name` attribute that has the value of the `delete[]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="rc1" class="actionitem">
<fieldset>
<legend>Action Item</legend>
<table>
</table>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="aid[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="delete[]">
<button class="removeBtn" type="button">Remove</button>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

​

```
$(function(){
  $("button.removeBtn").click(function(){
    var el = this;
    if (confirm("Please press OK to confirm")) {
        $(el).parents("fieldset").find("input[name='delete[]']").val('1');
        $(el).parents(".actionitem").slideUp('slow', function() {
            $(el).parents(".actionitem").hide();
        });
    }
  })
​})​
```

Comment: I have tried same methodology by change the find parameter to either "input[name='delete[]']" or "input[name='delete\\[\\]']" find in other answer, both not work. It is submitted a empty value (last element of array).

    [deleted] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 
        )